# Count unique words in a string using dplyr (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

Let's say I have a string as follows:

```
string <- "the home home on the range the friend"
```

All I want to do is determine which words in the string appear at least 2 times.

The psuedocode here is:

- Count how many times each word appears
- Return list of words that have more than two appearances in the string

**Final result should be a list featuring both `the` and `home`, in that order.**

I am hoping to do this using the tidyverse, ideally with stringr or dplyr. Was attempting to use tidytext as well but have been struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(x = str_split(string, "\\s+", simplify = T) %>% t) %>% 
  add_count(x) %>% 
  filter(n >= 2) %>% 
  distinct %>% 
  pull(x)  

#> [1] "the"  "home"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can split the string by space, get the `table` and subset based on frequency

```
out <- table(strsplit(string, "\\s+")[[1]])
out[out >=2]

home  the 
   2    3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `tidytext` and `tidyverse`, where we first separate each word (`unnest_tokens`), then we can count each word and sort by frequency. Then, we keep only words that have more than 1 observation, then use `tibble::deframe` to return a named vector.

```
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)

tibble(string) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, string) %>%
  count(word, sort = TRUE) %>%
  filter(n >= 2) %>%
  deframe()
```

**Output**

```
 the home 
   3    2
```

Or if you want to leave as a dataframe, then  you can just ignore the last step with `deframe`.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(string) %>%
  separate_rows(string) %>%
  count(string, sort = TRUE) %>%
  filter(n >= 2)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  string     n
  <chr>  <int>
1 the        3
2 home       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `quanteda` that prints "the" before "home" as requested in the original post.

```
library(quanteda)
aString <- "the home home on the range the friend"
aDfm<- dfm(tokens(aString))
# extract the features where the count > 1
aDfm@Dimnames$features[aDfm@x > 1]
```

...and the output:

```
> aDfm@Dimnames$features[aDfm@x > 1]
[1] "the"  "home"
```